# Rescaled solution of the PDE Vlasov equation are again solutions

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, substitution, chain-rule

In order to use the advantages of rescaling, I want to show that a rescaled solution of the Vlasov equation is again a solution. The setting is a gravitational Vlasov-Poisson system, which is a system of partial differential equations, meaning that $f$ is a distribution function depending on $x, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and we have the potential given by

$$U_f = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \iint \frac{f(x,v,t)}{|x - y|} dv dy.$$

To show: If $f(x,v,t)$ solves the Vlasov equation, i.e.
$$\partial_t f + v \cdot \nabla_x f - \nabla_x U \cdot \nabla_v f = 0,$$,
then for every $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$,
$\frac{\beta}{\alpha} f \left( \frac{x}{\alpha}, \beta v, \frac{t}{\alpha \beta} \right)$ is also a solution to the Vlasov equation.

My attempt:
Let $g = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} f \left( \frac{x}{\alpha}, \beta v, \frac{t}{\alpha \beta} \right)$. Then

$$U_g = \frac{\alpha^4}{\beta^2} U_f$$

and

$$\partial_t g + v \cdot \nabla_x g - \nabla_x U_g \cdot \nabla_v g = \frac{1}{\alpha \beta} \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2} Df(y, w, s) + \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2} v \cdot \nabla_x f(y, w, s) - \frac{\alpha^4}{\beta^2} \nabla_x U_{f(y, w, s)} \cdot \beta \nabla_v f (y, w, s)$$
$$= \frac{1}{\alpha^3} Df(y, w, s) + \frac{1}{\alpha^3} w \cdot \nabla_x f(y, w, s) - \frac{\alpha^4}{\beta} \nabla_x U_{f(y, w, s)} \cdot \nabla_v f (y, w, s),$$

where $y = \frac{x}{\alpha}, w =\beta v, s = \frac{t}{\alpha \beta}.$

Do you spot my mistake or could you help me, doing it correctly?

Thank you in advance!